# fill only bottom stacks in a stacked plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

```
dat <- data.frame(
  g=rep(c("A","B"),each=4), 
  val=c(109,260,178,203,89,180,40,130), 
  var=rep(c("m","t"), each=2,times=2), 
  dim=rep(c("x","y"),times=4)
) 

ggplot(aes(y=val, x=g, fill=dim), data=dat) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~var)
```

Is there a way to tell `ggplot2` not to fill the top (red) stacks? Ideally I would only want to show the red outline of the top stacks and fill the bottom stacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use manual scales, and set the fill to `NA`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(g, val, fill = dim, color = dim)) + 
  geom_col(size = 2) + 
  facet_wrap(~var) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('firebrick', 'navy')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, 'navy'))
```

[image]